# /dev/disk0 disappears

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook-pro

On my Macbook Pro mid-2014 (have had it for only a week) I am having an issue where the primary hard drive (at `/dev/disk0`) just disappears from the system, thus crashing. The only reason I know that it disappears is that I had terminal open one time when it happened and did a quick "ls /dev/disk*". I can't seem to find any information about this problem online.

I just had this happen again. I ran the following program:

`watch -n 1 "ls /dev/*disk*"`

This started out with the following:

`/dev/disk0
/dev/disk0s1
/dev/disk0s2
/dev/disk0s3
/dev/rdisk0
/dev/rdisk0s1
/dev/rdisk0s2
/dev/rdisk0s3`

After awhile suddently the only thing displayed from my watch command is:

`/dev/disk0s2
/dev/rdisk0s2`

Which is the Macintosh HD partition of the drive.

Comment: Wow - that's really strange. Have you looked over the console logs to see what sort of kernel messages (or other messages) arrive around that(those) fateful moment(s)?

Comment: I don't see anything that would seem to cause this issue from console. Of course I only have a few minutes to sift through it, before things crash again.

Comment: I should also point out that when I boot to System Recovery, I can't see the primary drive in Disk Utility as well. Genius bar appointment setup for tomorrow.

Comment: It sounds like a hardware failure. Hopefully the cable is all you need or just reseating the drive module / cabling.

Comment: I'm going to try re-seating the drive when I get home tonight; unfortunately I haven't become nerdy enough to carry my tool set in my laptop bag. Hopefully that's all. Regardless the laptop is less than a week old with Apple Care, so it'll be covered.